# Decoding an encoded string

Tags: ios, nsstring, base64, decode

I have fetched data from sqlite database using CoreData, and got NSString value:

```
"SxzYEWe6vE2ggLy5k9XV0Q24QJoOfvrHt9jCpq8CgCkGvfdgghjPIhDH0qZkNXjSHQJEw0cbGzFEoqZSIpImoqcuc8iA57oRne31fxgigPLWiAyAjjNnam68Z25hArGzDXudEA1AXoSM1TmlLMSV6c3XfDZM/IPPR245K5+DawOH5M8ZdUnbDyqVKRsi6KvqKou7mVA8DoZWrPBgN5YbvVC/da0F9QHCcq8Di8dNQ2/sf/oVs/A+ThHnglkscKyFuQ3FH+HNjENG2ZHtyWe1fQ=="
```

It seemed to be a `base64` encoded string. I tried many ways to decode the string using:

```
NSData *dataString = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:data.desc options:0];
NSString *textMeaning = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// textMeaning return (null).
```

has anyone seen this encoded string before and know how to decode it?

Comment: With no context I'd say : `Hello i'm a string with no meaning`

Comment: checking www.base64decode.org, your string apparently has indeed no meaning: "KgM@~Ƿ¦)`"Ҧd5xDG1DR"&.sȀ"ֈ3gjngna{@^9,ĕ|6L". So, before checking NSData conversion methods, you should check how and where you got that string from.

Comment: Where did this string come from? You need to find out how it was encoded in the first place before you can decode it.

Comment: I already checked with www.base64decode.org, and got same result. But I expected the string should be HTML string to use for webview. The encoded string comes from sqlite database so I have no idea how that string was encoded.

Comment: This encoded string is meaning of a English word, so I expect it would be an html string to display in a UIWebView.

Comment: As per auco comment your output is VERY danger for nsstring. It will definitely giving you null

Comment: same situation i faces . i get html encodeded data in base64 format from server, i have to show this html in UIWebView. if u find any solution please inform me i am stuck in this  problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this base64 method to decode,

```
NSString *decodeString = @"Apple";

    //Encode String

    NSData *encodeData = [decodeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64String = [encodeData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSLog(@"Encoded String Value: %@", base64String);


    //Decode String

    NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
    NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Decoded String Value: %@", decodedString);
```